# Removing apostrophes from regex pattern

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm a little new to regex and have written a simple regex to retrieve the word "Preview" from the from the string below.

> Time: '333333333333333333316:06:55 -232323' Permission: 'Preview' Teacher name: '4444444444444ffffffffffff' Student: 'cccccccccccssssssssss' Exam score: 'eeeeeeeeeeeA'

This is my regex expression below

```
Permission:\s?'([a-zA-z]+)'\s?Teacher name
```

I want to recreate my regex expression NOT to have apostrophes in it.

I plan to use this regex in `REGEX_SUBSTR` expression in an oracle query and it seems not to consume my regex with apostrophe very well.

How do i do that?

I know regex has many formats, so if anyone knows a better pattern, please feel free to suggest.

Comment: Please [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: FYI: note that [`[a-zA-z]` matches more than just letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

You can use your current regex pattern (corrected as per Wiktor's comment!) by escaping the single quotes:

```
regexp_substr(<your string>, 'Permission:\s?''([a-zA-Z]+)''\s?Teacher name')
```

or more cleanly by using [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218):

```
regexp_substr(<your string>, q'[Permission:\s?'([a-zA-Z]+)'\s?Teacher name]')
```

which lets you leave the single quotes as they were originally, and put the whole thing inside a set of delimited single quotes, using a delimiter that doesn't appear in your actual content - I've used square brackets here, so `q'[ ... ]'`. That lets whatever is inside, the `...` part, include unescaped single quotes.

Demos:

```
with t (str) as (
  select q'[Time: '333333333333333333316:06:55 -232323' Permission: 'Preview' Teacher name: '4444444444444ffffffffffff' Student: 'cccccccccccssssssssss' Exam score: 'eeeeeeeeeeeA']' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(str, 'Permission:\s?''([a-zA-Z]+)''\s?Teacher name')
from t;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'PERMISSION:\S?'
----------------------------------
Permission: 'Preview' Teacher name
```

or:

```
with t (str) as (
  select q'[Time: '333333333333333333316:06:55 -232323' Permission: 'Preview' Teacher name: '4444444444444ffffffffffff' Student: 'cccccccccccssssssssss' Exam score: 'eeeeeeeeeeeA']' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(str, q'[Permission:\s?'([a-zA-Z]+)'\s?Teacher name]')
from t;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,Q'[PERMISSION:\S
----------------------------------
Permission: 'Preview' Teacher name
```

To just get the word 'Preview' you can use `regexp_replace()` with a back-reference:

```
with t (str) as (
  select q'[Time: '333333333333333333316:06:55 -232323' Permission: 'Preview' Teacher name: '4444444444444ffffffffffff' Student: 'cccccccccccssssssssss' Exam score: 'eeeeeeeeeeeA']' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(str,
  '(.*Permission:\s?'')([a-zA-Z]+)(''\s?Teacher name.*)', '\2', 1, 1)
from t;

REGEXP_
-------
Preview
```

or

```
with t (str) as (
  select q'[Time: '333333333333333333316:06:55 -232323' Permission: 'Preview' Teacher name: '4444444444444ffffffffffff' Student: 'cccccccccccssssssssss' Exam score: 'eeeeeeeeeeeA']' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(str,
  q'[(.*Permission:\s?')([a-zA-Z]+)('\s?Teacher name.*)]', '\2', 1, 1)
from t;

REGEXP_
-------
Preview
```